# Inverse Modulo (NT)

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. If $a\equiv (3^{2n}+4)^{-1}\pmod{9}$, what is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $9$?

I don't have a great knowledge of Number Theory, so please don't be too complex in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$a\equiv (3^{2n}+4)^{-1} \pmod{9} \implies a(9^n+4) \equiv 1 \pmod{9
}\implies 4a \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: What is the method you used called?

Comment: @Skupp yes that is almost correct, it's a number when multiplied by 4 and divided by 9 gives a remainder 1

Comment: @Skupp It's just modular arithmetic.